# Let$\ p_n$ be the$\ n$-th prime. Can you give me a proof for$\ \prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{p_i-1}{p_i}=P\approx \frac{1}{11.0453}$?

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers, infinite-product

I found$\ \prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{p_i}{p_i-1}\approx 11.0453$ on [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*+3%2F2+*+5%2F4+*+7%2F6+*+...). Moreover, writing a paper, should one provide a proof or it is trivial? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The equation looks incorrect. I think you mistyped it, the title question is different.

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi Isn't$\ \prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{p_i-1}{p_i}= \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{p_i}{p_i-1}}$?

Comment: Same Wolfram|Alpha, when graphing the product, shows the partial product going over 12 at i=140 or so.

Comment: @Bahbar Oh dear, you're right. I should trust Wolfram|Alpha less. Well, is there a limit at all?

Comment: @Numberlover no, this is the result on the divergence of the harmonic series in disguise. See my answer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product#Examples

Comment: Try checking Euler product

Comment: Thank you all. I have a related, more intriguing question, if you desire: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929691/let-p-n-be-the-n-th-prime-does-lim-n-to-infty-log-log-n-prod-i-1

Comment: Please include additional context in your questions: where have these product come from? Why are you interested in them? In this site, we are interested in well-composed question that include more background information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product in the body of the question is
$$
\prod_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p}}
$$
which is $\zeta(1)$, or rather, which would be $\zeta(1)$, if the sum defining the Riemann zeta function on the half-plane $\text{Re} (s) > 1$ converged at $s = 1$.

Unfortunately, it doesn't converge; the Riemann $\zeta$ function has a pole at $s = 1$. (This is the multiplicative version of the failure of the harmonic series to converge.) Informally, the product in the body of the question is infinite (and its reciprocal, which is the product in the title of the question is zero). The value that Wolfram Alpha provides appears to be a truncation of this product.

Comment: I see, thank you! I have a related, more intriguing question, if you desire: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929691/let-p-n-be-the-n-th-prime-does-lim-n-to-infty-log-log-n-prod-i-1

Answer (score 1):

It is quite clear that the result is wrong. Let me consider $$P_n=\ \prod_{i=1}^{10^n} \frac{p_i}{p_i-1}$$ The numerical values are $$P_1=6.33123$$ $$P_2=11.2676$$ $$P_3=16.0086$$ $$P_4=20.5935$$ $$P_5=25.0748$$ $$P_6=29.4866$$

Comment: Yep, you're right. I have a related, more intriguing question, if you desire: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929691/let-p-n-be-the-n-th-prime-does-lim-n-to-infty-log-log-n-prod-i-1