# Let$\ p_n$ be the$\ n$-th prime. Is$\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \log \log n \prod_{i=1}^{\lfloor \log n \rfloor} \frac{p_i-1}{p_i}>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers, infinite-product

I'm less than a novice in analysis, I don't even know how to approach this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is $e^{-\gamma}$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).
This is a direct consequence of

> [Mertens' $3^{rd}$ theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems)
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \log x \prod_{\substack{p\,\le\,x\\p \text{ prime}} }\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) = e^{-\gamma}$$

By [Prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), we know $p_n \sim n\log n$, so 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{\log p_n} = 1$$

If we substitute $x$ by $p_n$ in Mertens' theorem and multiply its LHS by $\displaystyle\;\frac{\log n}{\log p_n}$, we get

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \log n \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_i}\right)
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n}{\log p_n} \left[ \log p_n \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_i}\right)\right]\\ 
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \log p_n \prod_{\substack{p\,\le\,p_n\\p\text{ prime}}}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) =
 e^{-\gamma}$$

For a proof of Mertens' theorem, see

- G.H Hardy's and E.M. Wright,
  Chapter XXII - The Series of Primes (3),
  *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*

It is theorem $429$ there.

Comment: +1. Any more recent reference for a complete proof?

Comment: @Did, Hardy and Wright is something close to standard. I browse over the proof of Mertens' theorem in the book, it seems pretty complete to me.

Comment: OK (I do not have the book with me). Nice to know.

Comment: I know that I should have asked this earlier, but why does$\ \log n \sim \log p_n$ follow from PNT? (I couldn't have)

Comment: Since you'll probably be offline for a while, I guess I'll ask a new question.
(I'm from Italy, so here it's already 1 p.m.)

Comment: @Numberlover  The equivalent form of PNT: $\quad p_n \sim n \log n\quad$ really means
$\displaystyle\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_n}{n\log n} = 1.\quad$  
Taking logarithm, this give us
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\log p_n - \log n - \log\log n \right) = 0
\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log p_n}{\log n} = 1 + \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log\log n}{\log n} = 1$$
( Note: I don't know where you can find the proof that PNT is equivalent to $p_n \sim n\log n$ but it is Theorem 8 of H&W's book. The proof of PNT is in Ch. XXII but I don't think H&W proved the equivalence.)

Comment: You can find a proof of the equivalence in Theorem 4.5 of Tom M. Apostol's book *Introduction To Analytic Number Theory*.

Comment: @achillehui Perfect, maybe I somewhat had figured out ($\ \log p_n \sim \log\left(n \log n\right)= \log n + \log \log n \sim \log n$ , isn't this, more informally I guess, right?), thank you again!

Comment: @achillehui I would actually have another question related to your answer. I thought it was correct to ask a new question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933297/if-p-n-is-the-n-th-prime-how-does-a-product-over-the-primes-less-than-p

Answer (score 2):

First note that, for every $u$ in $(0,\frac12]$, $$-u^2\leqslant\log(1-u)+u\leqslant0,$$ and the series $$\sum\limits_p\frac1{p^2}\leqslant\sum\limits_n\frac1{n^2}$$ converges hence, when $x\to\infty$,
$$\sum\limits_{p\lt x}\log\left(1-\frac1p\right)=c+o(1)-\sum\limits_{p\lt x}\frac1p,$$ for some constant $c$ On the other hand, the difference $$\sum\limits_{p\lt x}\frac1p-\log\log x,$$ converges to the so-called [Meissel-Mertens constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant) $M$, hence, considering the exponentials,
$$
\prod\limits_{p\lt x}\left(1-\frac1p\right)=\mathrm e^{c+o(1)}\,\mathrm e^{-M}\,\frac1{\log x},$$
in particular, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\log x\cdot\prod\limits_{p\lt x}\left(1-\frac1p\right)=\mathrm e^{c-M}\gt0.$$
The same result holds for the limit along the sequence $x=\lfloor\log n\rfloor$.

Comment: Could you explain me why isn't$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\,\log\log n\cdot\prod\limits_{p\lt\log n}\left(1-\frac1p\right)\gt0.$$ enough? I know more or less what the different types of limits are, but I'm not quite sure here.

Comment: The sequence could oscillate between, say, $1$ and $3$ without being convergent. For instance, $$\liminf_n(2+\sin n)\gt0,$$ but $\lim\limits_n(2+\sin n)$ does not exist.

Comment: Oh, now I see! Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

No, because as $n \to \infty$, we have that $x_n=\prod_{i=1}^{\log n} \frac{p_i-1}{p_i}=\prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{p_i-1}{p_i}$ diverges*, where $k=\log n \to \infty$.  Hence, we have:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\log \log nx_n=\log \log \infty=\infty$$

*(by your other question [Let$\ p_n$ be the$\ n$-th prime. Can you give me a proof for$\ \prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{p_i-1}{p_i}=P\approx \frac{1}{11.0453}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929661/let-p-n-be-the-n-th-prime-can-you-give-me-a-proof-for-prod-i-1-inft?lq=1))

Comment: Do you even need to know anything about that product? It is clearly increasing and $\log\log n$ already goes to infinity.

Comment: @Myself Yeah, but this shows that even without the $n$ it diverges, in case he decided to look at that. It's stronger.

Comment: @coolydudey60 Wait a second, I was busy at the moment, but you misunderstood my question. By my other question, we have that $x_n=\prod_{i=1}^{\log n} \frac{p_i-1}{p_i}=\prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{p_i-1}{p_i}$ converges to$\ 0$ . The product you are referring to is that in the body, which is different (the reciprocal of this)!