# As$\ n \to \infty$, how does a product over the primes less than$\ p_n$ equal the same product over the primes less than$\ n$?

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers, infinite-product

How is$$\ \lim_{x\to \infty} \log \log x \prod_{i< \log x} \frac{p_i -1}{p_i}= \\ \lim_{x\to \infty} \log \log x \prod_{p < \log x}_{p prime} \frac{p-1}{p}$$?

Comment: @i707107 That question is actually mine. The fact is I guess it would be more correct to allow the one who answered that, to gain some other points, since it has already been a while since I asked it.

Comment: I don't see the point that you had to ask the same question again, and it had already been answered there.

Comment: @i707107 My question is related to the answer of that question, more than the question itself. I simply didn't completely get a step of his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mertens's formula says that
$$
\prod_{\substack{p\le z \\ p \text{ prime}}} \frac{p-1}p \sim \frac1{e^\gamma\log z},
$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. (Here, $\sim$ means that the limit of the quotient of the two expressions equals $1$.) In particular,
$$
\prod_{i\le y} \frac{p_i-1}{p_i} = \prod_{\substack{p\le p_y \\ p \text{ prime}}} \frac{p-1}p \sim \frac1{e^\gamma\log p_y}.
$$
Since $p_y\sim y\log y$ by the prime number theorem, and $\log(y\log y) \sim \log y$, this last formula becomes
$$
\prod_{i\le y} \frac{p_i-1}{p_i} \sim \frac1{e^\gamma\log y}.
$$
These results give you what you need to deduce your equality.